# only envs inside uncover env

Tags: beamer, overlays, uncover

I was trying the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        hi \\
        \uncover<2->{
            \only<2>{
                hey \\
            }
            \only<3>{
                hello
            }
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

such that the 'hey/hello part' should still occupy space but should be revealed only after slide 1.

How can this be done?

I had thought separate `only` envs inside a single `uncover` could do it.

But that didn't work. The 'hey/hello' isn't occupying space in the first slide and the 'hi' jumps up to make way for the 'hey' in slide 2.

How can this be set right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to still occupy space, you can use `\visible` instead of `\only`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        hi \\
            \visible<2>{
                hey \\
            }
            \visible<3>{
                hello
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]